# Crystal Reports: Cannot insert some fields from Field Explorer to Report

Tags: crystal-reports, oracle10g

I have an existing report (Crystal Reports 11) that is based on two Oracle views. I have made 'Verify database' already, it's done and up to date.

My problem is that I can insert some fields to report but some other I cannot.

For example:

field Name (string(35)) is ok, but similar field Compamy (string(20)) I cannot insert to Report. Drag&drop does not work and small button "Insert to Report" in Field Explorer is disabled too.

Next symptom: when I try to use functionless field (e.g. Company) in Record Selection Formula Editor, Crystal Reports crash.

There is any way how to add these fields into Report?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've never imported from an Oracle view, so I don't know if this is feasible or not, but can you save your information to a static table first?

In my situation, my reports import from MS Access (which imports it's data from Lotus Notes).  I discovered that Crystal sometimes throws errors when linked to queries that have Access-specific functions.  So, the easiest way around is to save the data to a local table instead.

Comment: In my case, bad columns are not as functions in the view definition. In view it's defined as table column.

Answer (score 0):

For your crash probably need to install some the [service packs](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+2008+%28and+9.1,+XI+R1,+XI+R2%29+-+Version+and+Download+information+for+Service+Packs).